# add multiple onClickListeners on RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have added a new activity on itemView in recycler view but I want to add multiple activities on individual items. The tutorials are pretty good for Button but I can't figure out how to implement on the itemview.
the *recyclerview* called in MainActivity is as follows;

```
private String[] channelnames={"PTC Punjabi","Chakde TV","T-Series Punjabi", "9X Tashan", "Zee Punjabi" };
    private int[] channelimages={R.drawable.ptcpunjabi, R.drawable.chakde, R.drawable.tseries, R.drawable.ninex, R.drawable.zeepunjabi};
    private List<channel> channelList=new ArrayList<>();

 thirdrecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.third_recycler_view);
        thirdrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        channelList=new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager thirdlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        thirdrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(thirdlinearLayoutManager);
        for (int i=0;i < channelnames.length;i++){
            channel channel=new channel(channelnames[i],channelimages[i]);
            channelList.add(channel);
        }
```

the adapter and viewholder class is defined as;

```
public class channeladpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<channeladpater.Channelviewholder> {
    private List<channel> channelList;
    Context ctx;

    public channeladpater(List<channel> channelList) {
        this.channelList = channelList;
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Channelviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
        return new Channelviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Channelviewholder holder, int position)
    {
        channel channel=channelList.get(position);
        holder.channelname.setText(channel.getChannelname());
        holder.channelimage.setImageResource(channel.getChannelimage());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ctx, MainActivity2.class);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channelList.size();
    }

    public static class Channelviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView channelname;
        public CircleImageView channelimage;
        ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        Channelviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           this.channelname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            this.channelimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            this.itemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v,getLayoutPosition());


        }
        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic){
            this.itemClickListener=ic;
        }
    }
}
```

here I want to assign 1st image or textview (PTC punjabi/ R.drawable.ptcpunjabi) to MainActivity 2, the 2nd textview and imageview(Chakde Tv/R.drawable.chakde) to MainActivity 3 and so on. how can I call the text or image view combined to that when the whole card is clicked the next activity starts.
the MainActivity 2 is as follows;

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsoArrayList;

        Intent intent=getIntent();

        String API_Key = "  ";
        String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId="+channelID+"&maxResults=50&sort=date&key=[API_KEY]";
        com.currentmedia.punjabinews.adapter adapter;
        Context ctx;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
            videoDetailsoArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new adapter(MainActivity2.this,videoDetailsoArrayList);

            displayVideos();

        }


        private void displayVideos ()
        {
            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (jsonObject1.has("id")){
                                JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                                if (jsonVideoId.has("kind")){
                                    if(jsonVideoId.getString("kind").equals("youtube#video")){
                                        JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                                        JSONObject jsonObjectDefault=jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                                        String video_id=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                                        VideoDetails vd=new VideoDetails();

                                        vd.setVideoId(video_id);
                                        vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                                        vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                                        vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                                        videoDetailsoArrayList.add(vd);
                                    }
                                    //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                    adapter= new adapter(getApplicationContext(),videoDetailsoArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

In the String url, I want to add **channelId** for the list of **channelnames**, to avoid adding multiple activites.

```
PTC punjabi
UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA

Chakde Tv
UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ

T-series punjabi
UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ

9x tashan
UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A

zee punjabi
UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w
```

aformentioned is the list of channelIDs I want to assign to them so that when each image is selected from MAin Activity, individual channel activity starts.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 10 items in the list you don't need to create 10 activities for each item.

All you need is one same activity for showing details from the list in MainActivity.

When you press the item in list, you need to pass it's `position` and data(`channel` in your case) to the SecondActivity using `Intents`.

So let's make these changes.

In your adapter class:

You have setup the listener but make sure you are passing data.

```
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity2.class);
                // Using intent pass your data to MainActivity2 class
                intent.putExtra("Intent to MainActivity2", channel);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

MainActivity2 class :

Now you have to receive data from previous activity.
In your `onCreate()` of the activity after inflating the layout and before setting any views.

```
Channel channel = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Intent to MainActivity2");
```

From above code you are getting the data from which this intent has received, you may have received data from any activity too, so to specific from activity you refer using the `String` inside `getParcelableExtra()`

Now after getting data, call it's properties this way

```
yourTextView.setText(channel.channelname)
```

That's it. Now you can see clicking each item from list from previous activity and no more need extra activities.

For your reference you can see this [project](https://github.com/RajashekarRaju/Popular-Movies-Basic-App) follows similar approach.

Comment: Actually MainActivity 3 or 4 5 are new activities which include the json data for channel parsing with channel id..how can I use same activity ?

Comment: So all of your items in list doesn't refer to or have nothing to do with channel data? If few items data is different or needs to perform further operations, check the position or id for the current item you have clicked, and do different operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a listener param or method in Activity and send position or `Class` of Activity of item clicked to MainActivity and open Activities based on class is easier and used in Google's examples either.

```
abstract class BaseAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var listener: OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener? = null

    inner class MyViewHolder
        (// each data item is just a string in this case
        private val binding: ViewDataBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

        internal fun bind(obj: Any) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.obj, obj)
            binding.executePendingBindings()

            // Set click listener
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            listener?.run {
                onItemClicked(v, layoutPosition)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(
                layoutInflater,
                getLayoutIdForType(viewType),
                parent,
                false
            )
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return MyViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getDataAtPosition(position))
    }

   
    /**
     * Get data in position for RecyclerView row. This method is invoked inside
     * onBindViewHolder() method of RecyclerView
     *
     * @param position indicates the item for the current row
     * @return data for the current row
     */
    abstract fun getDataAtPosition(position: Int): Any
    
    /**
     * Get id of layout from R. This method is invoked from onCreateViewHolder method of Adapter
     *
     * @param viewType id of layout row of RecyclerView
     * @return id of layout
     */
    abstract fun getLayoutIdForType(viewType: Int): Int

    /**
     * RecyclerViewClickListener interface helps user to set a clickListener to the
     * RecyclerView. By setting this listener, any item of Recycler View can respond
     * to any interaction.
     */
    interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
        /**
         * This is a callback method that be overridden by the class that implements this
         * interface
         */
        fun onItemClicked(view: View, position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }
}
```

Data that contains class name and optional description

```
data class ActivityClassModel(val clazz: Class<*>, val description: String = clazz.name)
```

Adapter implementation

```
class ChapterSelectionAdapter(private val data: List<ActivityClassModel>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getDataAtPosition(position: Int): Any {
        return data[position]
    }
    override fun getLayoutIdForType(viewType: Int): Int {
        return R.layout.row_layout
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BaseAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

    private val activityClassModels = ArrayList<ActivityClassModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   
        val activityMainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // Add Activities to list to be displayed on RecyclerView
        activityClassModels.add(
            ActivityClassModel(
                Activity1Basics::class.java,
                "Activity BottomNavigationView with listener"
            )
        )

        val recyclerView = activityMainBinding.recyclerView

        recyclerView.apply {

            // Use fixed size for performance
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            // use a linear layout manager
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)

            // Add vertical divider
            addItemDecoration(
                DividerItemDecoration(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
                )
            )

            // Add Adapter
            recyclerView.adapter = ChapterSelectionAdapter(activityClassModels).apply {
                setOnItemClickListener(this@MainActivity)
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    override fun onItemClicked(view: View, position: Int) {
        Intent(this@MainActivity, activityClassModels[position].clazz).also {
            startActivity(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this java code? I am new to java programming and I cant understand the syntax of this code. can you please translate it in java like the code I provided in the question